# Appropriate caching for query execution in Cypher

Tags: caching, neo4j, cypher

I'm running parameterized Cypher queries with the Neo4j database embedded.
Each query is run with different input values, let's say for an ID. For each input value, the query is run 10 times.

As an example:

```
it#1 - Query 1, input 1, 10 times
it#2 - Query 1, input 2, 10 times
it#3 - Query 1, input 3, 10 times
it#4 - Query 2, input 1, 10 times
it#5 - Query 2, input 2, 10 times
```

Is it necessary to explicitly clear the cache for Neo4j, after running iteration #1 or after running iteration #3 (as it starts a new query)?
If clearing the cache is necessary, how do I do it in 2.2.0M03 Community?

Another thing is that I run the queries as follows:

```
initialize db
   for each input n
   i=0
      while(i<10)
         Result r;
         result = graphDb.execute(query,mapWithInputn)
         print result.resultAsString()
         result.close()
      end   
   end
close db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to flush the cache explicitly.

The query plan cache in Neo4j does not cache the query results, instead it caches the query plan. Every time you call `execute`, Neo4j checks if a query plan for that query string (independent of parameters) is in the query plan cache. If so it gets reused, otherwise the query plan will be build up and put into the cache.

With the plan in place, the query is run and results are returned.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! Also,when I run a query 10 times, I get results as `89  15 0 0 16 15 0 14 0 0` in milliseconds. The 89 is due to the query on a cold cache, but what is the reason for the change in time in others?

Comment: As you mention correctly, the first run does not benefit from node/relationship caching - they get loaded from your filesystem. The difference in subsequent calls is IMHO background noise, maybe JVM is doing garbage collection, OS is doing other stuff.

Comment: Just to clarify a small doubt here: if you don't explicitly clear the cache after #it1, it#2 will make use of the portion of the graph already in memory right? (the graph used for it#1)

Comment: exactly. Nodes, relationships and properties get loaded from disc on demand while traversing in it#1. In it#2 traversal is the same, but the nodes, rels are already there as java objects. This prevents file system accesses and therefore speeds up the query significantly.